# WCF Security Header Issue Seemingly Environment-Dependent

Tags: wcf, iis, soap

I have a WCF service which is configured to perform custom authentication through a `basicHttpsBinding`. The authentication process works fine on my development computer (Windows 7, IIS 7.5), but when deploying to a Windows Server 2008 computer (also IIS 7.5), WCF is refusing to recognize one the headers, specifically `Security` from `http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd`.

The client configuration is as follows:

```
<basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding" transferMode="Streamed" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967290" maxBufferSize="65536">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
...
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://myservice.com/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding"
        contract="Service.IMyService" name="MyServiceEndpoint" />
</client>
```

The server configuration is very similar, with the addition of the password validation info:

```
<service name="Service.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpsBinding" name="MyServiceEndpoint" 
              contract="Service.IMyService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" />
</service>
...
<basicHttpsBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding" transferMode="Streamed" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967290"
             maxBufferSize="65536">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpsBinding>
...
<behavior name="MyBehavior">
    <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" 
                customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Service.CredentialValidator, MyAssembly" />
        <serviceCertificate findValue="MyCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
    </serviceCredentials>
  ...
</behavior>
```

As expected, the client request includes a header with the authentication info:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <o:UsernameToken u:Id="uuid-d7168ad6-a829-49ae-9952-dd286ed2ba6d-7">
                <o:Username>username</o:Username>
                <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</o:Password>
            </o:UsernameToken>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    ...
</s:Envelope>
```

Locally, the header is understood:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        ...
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2013-07-19T17:28:00.631Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2013-07-19T17:33:00.631Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    ...
</s:Envelope>
```

But when deployed, no such luck:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode>s:MustUnderstand</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The header 'Security' from the namespace 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' was not understood by the recipient of this message, causing the message to not be processed.  This error typically indicates that the sender of this message has enabled a communication protocol that the receiver cannot process.  Please ensure that the configuration of the client's binding is consistent with the service's binding. </faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I've run through all of the typical ASP.NET / WCF setup steps including repairing and re-registering handlers and whatnot. Is there anything else to be considered that might be causing differences between these two environments?

Comment: Your comment "Windows Server 2003 computer (also IIS 7.5)" is incorrect. IIS is part of the operating system and on Windows Server 2003 it was IIS6 and for IIS7.5 you would have to be running Windows Server 2008 R2. You cannot install different versions of IIS on different versions of Windows Server

Comment: @MarkG Sorry, typo. The deployment machine is Windows Server 2008. I've corrected the question.

Comment: check if the server identifies the binding at all -  try to remove or make it malformed and see if it gives error

Comment: @YaronNaveh Yeah, the server doesn't hesitate to throw a configuration error if I change the binding name or set an invalid attribute value.

Comment: turn on wcf logging and trace to see if there are any extra errors

Comment: @YaronNaveh Unfortunately not. There is a 'Did not understand message header' warning for the OASIS namespace, then subsequent exceptions stemming from this.

Comment: try to create the aserver binding from code to ensure it is the right one (one option is via self hosting http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2010/10/wcf-self-hosting-also-in-vs-2010.html). also try to put the client on the new server box and see if it generates security. also check if maybe you have anotehr endpoint with no security and somehow when you change the url to the new server you change to that endpoint too.

Comment: Have you tried wsHttpBinding?

Comment: @MarkG wsHttpBinding isn't an option for me as I need request/response streaming.